# Vertical scrollbar in tkinter frame while using grid method

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am creating a GUI which contains buttons in grid using for loop. These button are placed in a frame derived from root frame. Each buttons also contains command for some specific task. Also, I am placing an image to these buttons. The code is given below.

```
    self.frame_side= Frame(root, bg='#ffffff', bd=1, relief='ridge')
    for i in range(5):
          self.button= Button(self.frame_side,state=NORMAL, bg='#ffffff', 
          cursor='hand2', bd=1, relief='ridge', command=lambda i=i+1: cnv1(i))
          photo_location = Image.open('conveyor-belt-icon.png')
          x_7=int(self.wh*0.81*0.04)
          y_7=int(self.h*0.05*1)
          image_name="image"+str(i)
          image_name=photo_location.resize((x_7,y_7), Image.ANTIALIAS)
          img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_name)
          self.button.config(image = img)
          self.button.image=img
          self.button.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10,pady=40)
```

Now I want to add a vertical scroll bar to this frame ('frame_side") so that if number of buttons increases then the frame can contains those. How do I do that.

I have tried using this following code:

```
    scrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_side,orient=VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.config(command= self.frame_side.yview)
    self.frame_side.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
```

But I am getting error as "Frame object has no attribute as yview".

Comment: tkinter `Frame` widget does not support scrolling. You can put the frame inside a `Canvas` widget and scroll the canvas to see different part of the frame.  There are few questions about scrollable frame in StackOverflow.

Comment: Made changes like this to add canvas. Still not getting desired output. 
'''canvas001=Canvas(self.frame_side)
self.frame_left=Frame(canvas001)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(self.frame_side,orient='vertical', command=canvas001.yview)
canvas001.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
myscrollbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
canvas001.pack(side='left')
canvas001.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame_left,anchor='nw')
self.frame_left.bind("<Configure>",canvas001.configure(scrollregion=canvas001.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200))'''

Comment: I have found my mistake. I wasn't binding the canvas as an event. Now it is working fine. Thanks for the help.